# Arithmetic addition and subtraction on large hexadecimal strings

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2012

How the arithmetic addition and subtraction can be carried out on large strings. For example, I have the following hexadecimal strings

```
string a1="B91EFEBFBDBDBFEFF39ABEE";
string a2="000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEEE";
```

then I want to do arithmetic addition a1+a2  to get the sum, not string concatenation.

And then arithmetic subtraction e.g. sum-a2 to get back string a1.

I tried to do

```
Int64 parseda1 = Int64.Parse(a1);
Int64 parseda2 = Int64.Parse(a2);
Int64 xyz = abc + abc;
MessageBox.Show(xyz.ToString("X"));// may be error in this as well
```

It trows exception, Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: I don't get it, your string contains 'x' and 'k', how is that a number?

Comment: Int64.TryParse() will allow you to parse without exception

Comment: Neither one of those strings represent an integer (whole) number.  That's why you get the Input string was not in a correct format exception.  What is the expected result of adding or substracting these two string?

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF - but `Int64.TryParse` will still not *parse* either one of those strings into an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited and removed x and k. It still gives the same error.

Comment: You still have an IPX in there. Is this supposed to be a hex string?

Comment: @Tim - agreed.  Didn't mean to infer that it would.  Just trying to help make the code more fault-tolerant.

Comment: In addition to IPX, there is also an O. I don't know what these strings are supposed to represent?

Comment: @Tim these two strings are hexadecimal and they should be added from left to right e.g. E with E, E with E, and B with E etc..

Comment: @ImranKanjoo What version of hexadecimal allows I, P, X, and O? Hex is 0-9,A-F.

Comment: Can you please state what format these strings are supposed to be in, i.e. what they mean?

Comment: If the result won't fit in an `Int64`, try `BigInteger` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually I have correct the strings. My main focus is not on the strings. The main focus is the addition of hexadecimal strings.

Comment: @ImranKanjoo - You should edit your question to indicate your strings represent hexadecimal numbers and you are trying to add and subtract them.  As it currently is your question is very misleading and open to interpretation (and a lot of confusion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want **really** large numbers, you can use the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) struct which represents an arbitrarily large signed integer. Try this:

```
string a1 = "B91EFEBFBDBDBFEFF39ABEE";
string a2 = "000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEEE";
BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.Parse(a1, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.Parse(a2, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger sum = num1 + num2;
Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString("X"));
Console.WriteLine((sum - num2).ToString("X")); //gets a1
```

---

Edit: 
Looks like `num1` gives us a negative number. That's probably not what you want. To fix that, read: [MSDN: BigInteger.Parse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285.aspx)

> "If value is a hexadecimal string, the Parse(String, NumberStyles)
>   method interprets value as a negative number stored by using two's
>   complement representation if its first two hexadecimal digits are
>   greater than or equal to 0x80. In other words, the method interprets
>   the highest-order bit of the first byte in value as the sign bit. To
>   make sure that a hexadecimal string is correctly interpreted as a
>   positive number, the first digit in value must have a value of zero.
>   For example, the method interprets 0x80 as a negative value, but it
>   interprets either 0x080 or 0x0080 as a positive value."

Comment: To use BigInteger don't forget to reference and include the System.Numerics namespace (System.Numerics.dll))

Comment: Also to just make note, `BigInteger` is much slower than "real" integers because there are no CPU operations that operate directly on this type like there are for `int` and `long`

Comment: Not sure why or if that's expected but that way num1 value is -1370997806539999934671115282 (note the negative sign).

Comment: @Sehnsucht check my answer now :)